# Is it possible to force a <div> not to have scrollbars

Tags: asp.net, html, css

this may be a very simple question, but is it possible to force a div not to have scrollbars? I have a div that i change the size of dynamically, and would like to force it to be fixed in size.
How would i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `overflow:hidden` in combination with the desired `width`/`height`.

Answer (score 2):

By default a div will not have scrollbars. It will only gain them if you set the [overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) property to a value that adds them. So long as it remains at `visible` or is changed to `hidden` the div will be whatever size you specify.

(Note that when overflow is visible, the div will remain at the given size, but the content might escape it.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) property: set to 'hidden'

Answer (score 0):

Declare a width and height, and then use the overflow property:

```
overflow: hidden
```

This will hide the scroll bars. Look at the other options as well.

You could choose which ones you want to display using `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`

Answer (score 0):

Use the **overflow** attribute on CSS as such:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
div.scroll {
height: 600px;
width: 800px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #666;
background-color: #ccc;
padding: 8px;
}
-->
</style>
```

Here's an example I wrote:

http://jsbin.com/orife/edit

Comment: Netscape 2 protection comments? In 2010? Really?